# Thin font looks bold, despite css stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am using the free, open source font "Roboto".

Here is my code:

```
font-family: 'Roboto',Sans-Serif;
font-weight: 100;
```

This code works great on my home page. It is thin and looks great.
But on my members area pages, it looks semi-bold.

I thought, perhaps it was because of the browser I was using (Google Chrome), but I debunked that idea because my homepage looks fine while using Google Chrome. Also, I haven't used any other browser.

Any tips on how to fix this issue?

Here is a screenshot to compare.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XibIK.png

Here HTML code for "Username": (Note, all text on this page is boldish looking. Not just username. So it's not just this code.)

```
<div class='title'>Username</div>
```

Here HTML code for "Money doesn't buy happiness":

```
<h1 class="h1">Money doesn't buy happiness</h1>
```

Comment: can you include screenshots to show the difference?

Comment: @RustyFlick can you please add link of your page, It might help a lot from that or make a jsfiddle and include the example here

Comment: include your `html` and `css` along with that as well

Comment: Can you show how you are adding the Font Family to your site. Eg. @import, <link> in the head??

Comment: Probably you have another css rule overwriting the `font-weight`. You can check this using the browsers dev tools, inspect the element and look at the applied css rules.

Comment: No, I checked Inspect Element. I use it all the time to check my work. It's not over-written.

Comment: Most likely, your members area pages are not correctly including the required font "Roboto". To check this, you can view the actual font being used in the "computed properties" section of the style inspector. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/09/DevTools-answers-What-font-is-that?hl=en.

Comment: It also may happens if you somewhere forgot to close `<strong>` tag. Or if some parent tag overwrite property `font-weight`

Comment: UPDATE: I used Inspect Element and tested other fonts and I am getting same results. I tested Segoe UI Light, and looks just like Segoe UI semi-bold

Comment: The font used for `Uesname` does not look like `Roboto`  (you can see it at the `a`) , so there must be a rule that changes the `font-family`  for the `h1` element.

Comment: I have figued out that when I check the "computed" section in Google's Inspect Element. It says that Arial font is rendering????

Comment: Is Roboto being properly loaded? Check your resources tab in developer tools. If you are loading the font externally, are you sure you're getting the file that contains the weight you have specified? Some files only have glyphs for certain weights, and if the `100` variant is being left out that might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

As the people stated in the comments, a parent class is over-ruling the `h1` and this results in bold text. I also see that you have a class `h1` on the `h1` element.

**CSS**

```
.title, .h1 {
   font-family: 'Roboto',Sans-Serif;
   font-weight: 100;
}
```

Or with `!important` to override the `font-weight`. Please note that `!important` will be helpful on classes that you always want to be same. For example on headings or buttons.

```
.title, .h1 {
       font-family: 'Roboto',Sans-Serif;
       font-weight: 100 !important;
}
```